# How can I improve those voltage annotations

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-circuit-lib

In France, we draw an arrow above or below a dipole to represent the potential difference between its two poles. I'm trying to automate this using the ideas of the `tikz` circuits library (not `circuitz`). The code is adapted from the `direction info` code.

I have the following code. It works but it is far from perfect.

- It allows upsidedown labels.
- Sometimes labels overlap the arrow.
- I have the feeling that it complies only partially with `tikz`'s way of handling styles and options.
- It is verbose (not refactored).

What and how should I do to improve this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\tikzset{%
  voltage info/.is family,
  voltage info/vertical offset/.initial = .5,
  voltage info/arrow direction/.initial = ->,
  voltage info/horizontal offset/.initial = 2,
  voltage info/label position/.initial = above,
  voltage info/label rotate/.initial = 0,
  voltage info/label/.initial = {}
}

\tikzset{%
  voltage arrow/.style = {%
    /utils/exec = {%
      \pgfsetarrowoptions{direction ee}{%
        .4*\the\tikzcircuitssizeunit+.3*\the\pgflinewidth}},
    > = direction ee},
  voltage info sloped/.style = {% 
    append after command = {%
      \bgroup
        [voltage info/.cd,#1]
        [current point is local=true]
        [every voltage info/.try]
        [shift={($(\tikzlastnode.north)+(0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/vertical offset}\tikzcircuitssizeunit)$)}]
        [voltage arrow,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/arrow direction}]
        (-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/horizontal offset}\tikzcircuitssizeunit,0)
        edge[line to] 
        node[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/label
          position},transform shape,rotate = \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage
          info/label rotate}] {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/label}}
        (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/horizontal offset}\tikzcircuitssizeunit,0)
      \egroup
    }
  },
  voltage info' sloped/.style = {% 
    append after command = {%
      \bgroup
        [voltage info/.cd,label position = below,#1]
        [current point is local=true]
        [every voltage info/.try]
        [shift={($(\tikzlastnode.south)+(0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/vertical offset}\tikzcircuitssizeunit)$)}]
        [voltage arrow,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/arrow direction}]
        (-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/horizontal offset}\tikzcircuitssizeunit,0)
        edge[line to] 
        node[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/label
          position},transform shape,rotate = \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage
          info/label rotate}] {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/label}}
        (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/horizontal offset}\tikzcircuitssizeunit,0)
      \egroup
    }
  },
  voltage info/.style = {% 
    append after command = {%
      \bgroup
        [voltage info/.cd,#1]
        [current point is local=true]
        [every voltage info/.try]
        [shift={($(\tikzlastnode.north)+(0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/vertical offset}\tikzcircuitssizeunit)$)}]
        [voltage arrow,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/arrow direction}]
        (-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/horizontal offset}\tikzcircuitssizeunit,0)
        edge[line to] 
        node[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/label
          position},rotate = \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage
          info/label rotate}] {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/label}}
        (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/horizontal offset}\tikzcircuitssizeunit,0)
      \egroup
    }
  },
  voltage info'/.style = {% 
    append after command = {%
      \bgroup
        [voltage info/.cd,label position = below,#1]
        [current point is local=true]
        [every voltage info/.try]
        [shift={($(\tikzlastnode.south)+(0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/vertical offset}\tikzcircuitssizeunit)$)}]
        [voltage arrow,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/arrow direction}]
        (-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/horizontal offset}\tikzcircuitssizeunit,0)
        edge[line to] 
        node[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/label
          position},rotate = \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage
          info/label rotate}] {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/label}}
        (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/horizontal offset}\tikzcircuitssizeunit,0)
      \egroup
    }
  }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
  \draw (0,0) to[resistor = {% 
    voltage info = {label = $u_R$},
    voltage info' = {label = $u_R$}}] (2,2);
  \draw (2,0) to[resistor = {% 
    voltage info sloped = {label = $u_R$},
    voltage info' sloped= {label = $u_R$}}] (4,2);
  \begin{scope}[shift = {(4.5,2)}]
    \draw (0,0) 
          to[resistor = {voltage info sloped = {label = $u_R$}}]
          ++ (2,0)
          to[resistor = {voltage info sloped = {label = $u_R$}}]
          ++ (0,-2)
          to[resistor = {voltage info sloped = {label = $u_R$}}]
          ++ (-2,0);          
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

I believe I can help with your first two points.

> - It allows upsidedown labels.

This is because you have the `sloped` option set. If you turn that off, then your right-hand example becomes

[image]

That fixes the upsidedown labels. But then...

> - Sometimes labels overlap the arrow.

This can be fixed by giving the `auto` option for your `voltage info` nodes. This results in...

[image]

The only problem is that your left-hand example still looks a bit off...

[image]

But that's fixed by using the `auto,swap` options for your `voltage info'` nodes, which puts those labels on the other side of their arrows.

[image]

Complete code follows.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\tikzset{%
  voltage info/.is family,
  voltage info/vertical offset/.initial = .5,
  voltage info/arrow direction/.initial = ->,
  voltage info/horizontal offset/.initial = 2,
  voltage info/label position/.initial = above,
  voltage info/label rotate/.initial = 0,
  voltage info/label/.initial = {}
}

\tikzset{%
  voltage arrow/.style = {%
    /utils/exec = {%
      \pgfsetarrowoptions{direction ee}{%
        .4*\the\tikzcircuitssizeunit+.3*\the\pgflinewidth}},
    > = direction ee},
  voltage info sloped/.style = {% 
    append after command = {%
      \bgroup
        [voltage info/.cd,#1]
        [current point is local=true]
        [every voltage info/.try]
        [shift={($(\tikzlastnode.north)+(0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/vertical offset}\tikzcircuitssizeunit)$)}]
        [voltage arrow,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/arrow direction}]
        (-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/horizontal offset}\tikzcircuitssizeunit,0)
        edge[line to] 
        node[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/label
          position},transform shape,rotate = \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage
          info/label rotate}] {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/label}}
        (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/horizontal offset}\tikzcircuitssizeunit,0)
      \egroup
    }
  },
  voltage info' sloped/.style = {% 
    append after command = {%
      \bgroup
        [voltage info/.cd,label position = below,#1]
        [current point is local=true]
        [every voltage info/.try]
        [shift={($(\tikzlastnode.south)+(0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/vertical offset}\tikzcircuitssizeunit)$)}]
        [voltage arrow,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/arrow direction}]
        (-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/horizontal offset}\tikzcircuitssizeunit,0)
        edge[line to] 
        node[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/label
          position},transform shape,rotate = \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage
          info/label rotate}] {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/label}}
        (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/horizontal offset}\tikzcircuitssizeunit,0)
      \egroup
    }
  },
  voltage info/.style = {% 
    append after command = {%
      \bgroup
        [voltage info/.cd,#1]
        [current point is local=true]
        [every voltage info/.try]
        [shift={($(\tikzlastnode.north)+(0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/vertical offset}\tikzcircuitssizeunit)$)}]
        [voltage arrow,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/arrow direction}]
        (-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/horizontal offset}\tikzcircuitssizeunit,0)
        edge[line to] 
        node[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/label
          position},auto,rotate = \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage
          info/label rotate}] {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/label}}
        (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/horizontal offset}\tikzcircuitssizeunit,0)
      \egroup
    }
  },
  voltage info'/.style = {% 
    append after command = {%
      \bgroup
        [voltage info/.cd,label position = below,#1]
        [current point is local=true]
        [every voltage info/.try]
        [shift={($(\tikzlastnode.south)+(0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/vertical offset}\tikzcircuitssizeunit)$)}]
        [voltage arrow,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/arrow direction}]
        (-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/horizontal offset}\tikzcircuitssizeunit,0)
        edge[line to] 
        node[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/label
          position},auto,swap,rotate = \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage
          info/label rotate}] {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/label}}
        (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/voltage info/horizontal offset}\tikzcircuitssizeunit,0)
      \egroup
    }
  }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
  \draw (0,0) to[resistor = {% 
    voltage info = {label = $u_R$},
    voltage info' = {label = $u_R$}}] (2,2);
  \draw (2,0) to[resistor = {% 
    voltage info sloped = {label = $u_R$},
    voltage info' sloped= {label = $u_R$}}] (4,2);
  \begin{scope}[shift = {(4.5,2)}]
    \draw (0,0) 
          to[resistor = {voltage info = {label = $u_R$}}]
          ++ (2,0)
          to[resistor = {voltage info = {label = $u_R$}}]
          ++ (0,-2)
          to[resistor = {voltage info = {label = $u_R$}}]
          ++ (-2,0);          
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very good starting point. Thanks. But sometimes I do want labels to be sloped *and* not upside down.

Comment: Could you provide a concrete example of the kind of sloping-but-not-upside-down situation that you have in mind?

Comment: Sorry. My previous comment was total nonsense. Of course, as in my last example, I can use `voltage info` instead of `voltage info sloped`. This seems to mimmic to build-in `info`/`info sloped` behaviour which looks good for me. `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
  \draw (2,2) to[resistor = {info sloped = $R$}] (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 2):

I've made, this, but not with `tikz`, with `PSTricks` and especiallythe package `pst-circ` that can draw circuits diagrams... I believe it is more powerful (and handier), but it's my point of view...

I've made a MWE down below.

It's the line `labelangle=:U` that determines the angle between the component and the direction of the label (and the name too). `:U` will put it in the same sense, but you can specify any angle you want.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\usepackage{pst-circ}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](0, -1)(12, 4)
\pnode(0, 0){A}
\pnode(3, 3){B}
\pnode(4, 0){C}
\pnode(7, 3){D}
\pnode(8, 3){E}
\pnode(11, 3){F}
\pnode(11, 0){G}
\pnode(8, 0){H}
\resistor[labeloffset=0,
    labelangle=:U,
    tensionlabel=$u_R$,
    tensionoffset=0.7,
    tensionlabeloffset=1](A)(B){$R$}
\resistor[labeloffset=0,
    tensionlabel=$u_R$,
    tensionoffset=0.7,
    tensionlabeloffset=1](C)(D){$R$}
\resistor[labeloffset=0,
        tensionlabel=$u_R$,
    tensionoffset=-0.7,
    tensionlabeloffset=-1,
    directconvention=false](F)(E){$R$}
\resistor[labeloffset=0,
    %labelangle=:U,         TO PUT THE R IN THE SAME SENSE AS THE RESISTOR
    tensionlabel=$u_R$,
    tensionoffset=-0.7,
    tensionlabeloffset=-1,
    directconvention=false](G)(F){$R$}
\resistor[labeloffset=0,
    tensionlabel=$u_R$,
    tensionoffset=-0.7,
    tensionlabeloffset=-1,
    directconvention=false](H)(G){$R$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the ouput :

[image: Output]